# Immediately kill MySQL

Tags: mysql, services

I have a shared server that someone has compromised Wordpress. Is there an easy way to kill MySQL. I am stopping the service but it is just sitting and waiting.... to stop

```
Shutting down MySQL (Percona Server)...........................
```

Comment: Do you have root? `sudo killall -9 mysqld`

Comment: @GregHewgill yes I have root. Thanks I will try that

Comment: @GregHewgill That worked great, thanks, I will post my answer

Answer (score 1):

The following solved my problem:

```
sudo killall -9 mysqld
```